# UK Tier2 visa resigned and rejoining. Should I apply for a visa again?

Tags: uk, working-visas, us-residents

I was working as a post-doctoral researcher in the UK under a Tier 2 visa. Then I resigned my job and returned to my home country. About a year later, I am now planning to go to the UK and rejoin with the same job. Should I apply for a visa again?

I have a residence permit, which will expire in May 2018. However I can return home before that.

Comment: Oops... should've migrated this to Expats...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to re-apply. Your visa and residence permit would have become invalid when you left your sponsor. It would be unwise to attempt to enter the UK with the residence permit, as it would be considered an illegal entry. You should apply for a new Tier 2, once the cooling off period from your earlier Tier 2 has expired.